# null and default behaviour with immutables

Tags: java, immutability

Using https://immutables.github.io in my Java App

My immutable POJO:

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface AdditionalInfo {

  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default String getCountry() {
    return "US";
  }
}
```

My code that creates POJO

```
ImmutableAdditionalInfo.builder().country(countryVar).build()
```

If countryVar is null, getCountry will return null. This seems counter intuitive to me, as a default to me, is best used if no value can be set. 
I can have null checks in the app code that creates AdditionalInfo, but that seems less than optimal.

```
if (countryVar != null) {
    ImmutableAdditionalInfo.builder().country(countryVar).build()
} else {
    ImmutableAdditionalInfo.builder().build()
}
```

The builder generated code is:

```
this.country = builder.countryIsSet() ? builder.country : AdditionalTaxLineInfo.super.getCountry();
```

Whereas what I want is:

```
this.country = builder.countryIsSet() && builder.country != null ? builder.country : AdditionalTaxLineInfo.super.getCountry();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar question asked here: https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/294

Solution:

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class AdditionalInfo  {
    abstract @Nullable String getCountry();

    public String getCountryCanonical() {
      return getCountry != null ? getCountry : DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Nullable attributes](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#nullable-attributes).

Something like:

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface AdditionalInfo {

  @Nullable 
  @Value.Default
  default String getCountry() {
    return "US";
  }
}
```